# "No, more than that." --> "No, more expensive.", "More expensive.", "No, more.", "More."?

Tags: comparative

> How much did your shoes cost? ₤60? - **No, more than that**.

Is it natural to say instead of "No, more than that.":

"No, more expensive.",

"More expensive.",

"No, more.",

or just "More."?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only ones that sound non-fluent to me, as a US English speaker, are the ones with *expensive*.  They're not *wrong*, exactly, it's just that if I were answering with a full sentence, it would be "They cost more than ₤60", and anything else sounds like a reduced version of that sentence, so it sounds odd to use "expensive".

I might use the word *expensive* if I were creating an entirely new sentence, like, "No, they were more expensive than that."  But *they* in this case refers to the shoes and not the ₤60; *expensive* is applied to items, not usually prices themselves; I would say *these shoes are more expensive than those shoes*, but not *₤70 is more expensive than ₤60.*